# What is the last IP address that can be assigned to a class c subnet with a prefix of 192.168.56.128/26?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

What is the last IP address that can be assigned to a class c subnet with a prefix of 192.168.56.128/26?

How did you go about getting this answer (so that I can work them out myself in the future?)

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ gives useful network computations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
26-bit mask means 32 bits (address length) - 26 bits (mask length) = 6 address bits
2^6 = 64 addresses (0..63)
192.168.56.128 + 0 = 192.168.56.128 subnet
192.168.56.128 + 1 = 192.168.56.129 first address
.
.
192.168.56.128 + 62 = 192.168.56.190 last address
192.168.56.128 + 63 = 192.168.56.191 broadcast address
```